# Can a variable be used in macro expression?

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-11

Can a variable be used like this code in the macro expressions to retrieve values dynamically?

I am trying the code below which return as null.

```
var indexId = 45;

return CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.Users[indexId].DisplayName;
```

Comment: Can you give more context into where you are trying to use this macro and the exact code you are using?

Comment: I was trying to retrieve the user name dynamically. I figured I just needed to write that code on the same line and it worked.  {%indexId = 45;return CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.Users[indexId].DisplayName;%}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please see the macro syntax [documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/macro-expressions/macro-syntax#Macrosyntax-Compoundexpressionsanddeclaringvariables)

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the code should be on the same line. Earlier I was declaring the variable in separate line. So this works now

```
indexId = 45;return CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.Users[indexId].DisplayName;
```